# android - Parse app's id and client key

Tags: android, parse-platform, notifications, push-notification

I am working right now on a tutorial to send push notifications in android.

here is the link - https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications.

In the tutorial, it says -

// -------------------------------- TUTORIAL  -------------------------- //

**Create or open your Application class, and add the following line to your onCreate method:**

```
Parse.initialize(this, "YOUR_APP_ID", "YOUR_CLIENT_KEY");
```

**Make sure to replace "YOUR_APP_ID" and "YOUR_CLIENT_KEY" with your Parse app's id and client key. You can find these in your app's Settings page.**

// --------------------------------  TUTORIAL  -------------------------- //

My question is - where do I get those app's id and client key?

and also, maybe there is an easier way to send push notifications from my application? **what is classic way to send push notifications in android?**.

by push notifications I mean notification that will appear in the phone even when the app is closed, like email notification for example, or whatsapp.

thanks a lot!

Comment: [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/) is example with GSM

Answer (score 2):

In the parse dash board will find the required keys in the keys tab. Please refer the image below

[image]